# Thoughts on this approach for: EF5 Code First, Repository Pattern, UofW, etc etc

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5

I've been wading through the unbelievable amount of blogs/documentation/etc about EF Code First, Repositories, Unit of Work and so on.

I'm trying to create a convenient framework for my next project that handles:

1. Both web environment (HttpContext) and standalone (for ex a Windows Service)
2. Gives me the option to define repositories for specific entities or use a generic repo for simple queries.

I decided that I won't encapsulate EF in my repos. I don't see when we will ever consider switching to a different ORM.

So I came up with the following and I'd be happy to hear opinions!  :)

```
namespace Data.Repositories
{
internal class DbContextInstance
{
    public static readonly DbContext Context;

    static DbContextInstance()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["__DBCONTEXT"] == null)
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["__DBCONTEXT"] = new MyDbContext();

            Context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["__DBCONTEXT"] as MyDbContext;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Context == null)
                Context = new MyDbContext();
        }
    }
}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    //Implementation of repo. Similar to GenericRepository here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
    //whenever I need to access the context I'm using DbContextInstance.Context 
}
```

In the above generic repo I don't need to worry about passing a DbContext (like in the link I mention), because DbContextInstance worries about that. It's a single point where I can configure the connection string, etc. I kept that part simple, but we can enhance it to read the connection string name from somewhere.

Generic Repo is IDisposable - in the Dispose method I dispose the Context. The above code makes sure that there's no more than one Context in a session (either a HTTP Request or the life of an EXE app). Of course as long as it isn't disposed.

Units of work classes will simply instantiate repos and interact with them. They will be IDisposable as well and will dispose the repos.

I will do testing and mockups against the DB. I will have a script for resetting the DB and pre-populate it initial data. I find it best to test against the real thing and not some mockups that emulate things.

This code is bits and pieces from various places + some of my own creativity..

Can you see anything that may cause agony later when the app is already up and running? Throw it at my face!  ;)

Thanks! :)

Comment: How do you dispose the context at the end of a request? For me it looks like your context lifetime will potentially span multiple requests.

Comment: @Slauma: Thanks for reviewing the code! I figured I'd use using() blocks for the UofW instances. Btw, not sure the context can span across multiple requests, as it's stored in HttpContext.Items collection, which is per request.

Comment: Yes, but because you are holding the context in a static variable, it will stay there until the next request which creates a new context and overwrites the static variable. If you use the new context after that the old context is possibly not yet garbage collected, so you'd have perhaps entities attached to two different contexts -> trouble.

Comment: @justabuzz Don't re-implement the wheel. Use an IoC/DI framework

Comment: @Slauma - you're right! I overlooked that.

Comment: @Eranga - yeah, I am looking into StructureMap, seems fairly straight forward. Still trying to make sense of everything.. So many different approaches and ideas.

Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3):

The Context should be short lived - your code seems to imply that your Context will have a long lifetime and be shared. This will cause you grief.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! When it comes to web environment then I thought I'd maintain the same context for the entire Request. Is that considered long life? I see what you mean re non-HTTP environment..